# Kill external process started by batch file on Windows from within Python script

Tags: python, batch-file, operating-system, popen, kill

My program executes a specific script, after which it creates a process via **Popen** method by executing a .bat (batch) file.

The .bat file, in turn, executes another .exe file. The problem for me arises when I am trying to simply run `p.kill()` to terminate the .exe file process .bat file has started.

Instead of terminating all the processes, it just tries to kill the .bat file process, but not the .exe file's process that .bat file has created.

Is there a way for me to specifically kill the .exe process?

UPD: It seems like .bat file creates a separate .exe process which I cannot simply end with p.kill(), since it has different pid from the .bat's file process.

I tried killing it with running `os.system("taskkill /F /im process.exe")`, but it didn't touch the .exe process. Surprisingly, running the same taskkill command in the console did kill it.

Comment: can you show the rest of the code? I am testing this and works 100%. `import os` then
`os.system("taskkill /f /im  notepad.exe")` where I just used notepad as a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by running the `subprocess.call("taskkill /F /im process.exe")`.

I am not sure why `os.system` didn't work in the first place, perhaps it's due to its outdated nature. Hopefully, it helps those who will encounter a similar issue!